# How to safely remove Sass 3.4.23 (Selective Steve) and Install Dart Sass?

Tags: npm, sass

When I try to compile sass, an error says `Error: Invalid CSS after "...ame}: #{$value}": expected "{", was ";"`

This error output after the command: `sass css/custom.scss css/custom.css`

The one and only line in the scss file is `@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

After searching other forums, it seems I need to update my Sass compiler.

Previous commands that I ran were to uninstall and reinstall node. Now, I have these versions of node and npm:

```
node -v
>> v19.8.1

npm -v
>> 9.5.1
```

I had originally installed sass with `npm install sass`. But then I saw the documentation for dart-sass. So I ran `npm uninstall sass` and then ran `brew install sass/sass/sass` to install dart sass. However, I don't think it is compiling with the right version because I see:

```
sass -v 
>> Sass 3.4.25 (Selective Steve)
```

And this is odd because after I ran `brew install sass/sass/sass` it said sass/sass/sass 1.59.3 was successfully installed. Do I need to run `gem uninstall sass` to remove Selective Steve before I install Dart Sass? My concern is that it prompts me with

```
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    sass-3.4.25

foundation-rails-5.5.3.2 depends on sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
sass-rails-5.0.6 depends on sass (~> 3.1)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
```

Is it safe to continue with the uninstall given that I'll install or reinstall dart-sass?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully resolved this with `gem uninstall sass`. This removed the Selective Steve Sass and left me with 1.59.3 Dart Sass. I'm not able to compile. I was hesitant to try this because of the prompts it returned that I posted in the question. But so far, I have not had further issues.